# Eсть ли аналог enterEvent и leaveEvent в pyqt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Я хочу использовать `enterEvent` и `leaveEvent`, но для их использования нужно создавать новый объект и это неудобно.

Я хочу использовать конструкцию:

```
self.clicked.connect(self.fun)
```

но со свойствами `enterEvent` или `leaveEvent`

Есть ли аналоги?

---

**`Что мне приходится делать:`**

```
class Widget1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('1')

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('2')


class Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('1')

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('2')


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        wid1 = Widget1(self)
        wid2 = Widget2(self)
```

---

**`Что бы я хотел сделать`**:

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        wid1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        wid2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        
        wid1.???.connect(self.fun)
        wid1.???.connect(self.fun2)
        wid2.???.connect(self.fun2)
        wid2.???.connect(self.fun)
        
    def fun(self, event):
        print('1')

    def fun2(self, event):
        print('2')
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше чего вы хотите добиться? Что именно вам не удобно? Вы что хотите передать в вызываемый по клику метод обработчики событий `enterEvent` и/или `leaveEvent`? Для чего и что у вас в будет происходить в вызываемом методе?

Comment: @S.Nick Нет я имею в веду посторенние кода как в `clicked.connect` но со свойствами `enterEvent` или `leaveEvent`
Другими словами оно должно писаться как `clicked.connect`, но работать как `enterEvent` или `leaveEvent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации:

> `[virtual protected] void QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent *event)`
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован **в подклассе**
> для приема событий вxода в виджет, которые передаются в параметре события.
> Событие отправляется виджету, когда курсор мыши входит в виджет.

> `[virtual protected]void QWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)`
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован **в подклассе**
> для получения событий выхода из виджета, которые передаются в параметре события.
> Событие выхода отправляется виджету, когда курсор мыши покидает виджет.

Это первый вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget1(QtWidgets.QLabel):    # QWidget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("Widget1")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #f00;")
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('class Widget1: leaveEvent')
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('class Widget1: enterEvent')


class Widget2(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("Widget2")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00f;")
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('class Widget2: leaveEvent')
            
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('class Widget2: enterEvent')


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        wid1 = Widget1(self)
        wid2 = Widget2(self)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(wid1)           # , alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        layout.addWidget(wid2)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
    window.resize(300,300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Другой вариант, который используется в практике - это установка фильтра событий.

> `void QObject::installEventFilter(QObject *filterObj)`
>
> Устанавливает фильтр событий `filterObj` на этот объект.
>
> Например: `monitoredObj->installEventFilter(filterObj);`

Фильтр событий - это объект, который получает все события, отправленные этому объекту.
Фильтр может остановить событие или перенаправить его этому объекту.
Фильтр событий `filterObj` получает события через свою функцию `eventFilter()`.
Функция `eventFilter()` должна возвращать `True`,
если событие должно быть отфильтровано (т.е. остановлено);
в противном случае он должен вернуть `False`.

```
[virtual]bool QObject::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
```

Фильтрует события, если этот объект был установлен как фильтр событий для наблюдаемого объекта.
При повторной реализации этой функции, если вы хотите отфильтровать событие,
то есть остановить его дальнейшую обработку, верните `True`; в противном случае верните `False`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName('widget')
        
        self.wid1 = QLabel(objectName='widget_1', styleSheet="background-color: #f00;")
        self.wid1.setText("Widget1")
        self.wid2 = QLabel(objectName='widget_2', styleSheet="background-color: #00f;")
        self.wid2.setText("Widget2")
        
        self.wid1.installEventFilter(self)
        self.wid2.installEventFilter(self)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.wid1)       
        layout.addWidget(self.wid2)
        
    def fun(self, widget, event):
        print(f'{widget} -> {event}\n')
        
    def fun2(self, widget, event):
        print(f'{widget} -> {event}\n')

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.wid1 and event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.fun(self.wid1.objectName(), 'QEvent.Leave')
            return True
        elif obj is self.wid1 and event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.fun2(self.wid1.objectName(), 'QEvent.Enter')
            return True
        elif obj is self.wid2 and event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.fun(self.wid2.objectName(), 'QEvent.Leave')
            return True
        elif obj is self.wid2 and event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.fun2(self.wid2.objectName(), 'QEvent.Enter')            
            return True
            
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
    window.resize(300,300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]